En las columnas donde se está usando ISNULL, no está uniendo las tablas, por lo tanto no tienen coincidencia
Lo que estoy haciendo es unir estas cuatro tablas usando el UNION ALL, pero tengo un problema al momento de ver mi tabla de resultados, ya que en las columnas en donde estoy usando el comando ISNULL no me está uniendo las tablas y por lo tanto no tienen coincidencia. Sé que estoy usando mal el comando ISNULL, ¿cómo puedo corregir esa parte del codigo?
SELECT 

    FECHA,
    CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
    SUM(ts.CANTIDAD) as TRASLADOS,
    ISNULL('RECEPCIONES',0) AS RECEPCIONES,
    ISNULL('FACTURA',0) AS FACTURA,
    ISNULL('PRIORIDAD',0) AS PRIORIDAD

FROM 

ORACLE_INFO.dbo.tbl_TRANSACCIONES_INVENTARIO as ts

WHERE 

    TRANSACTION_TYPE IN ( 'WIP Assy Completion' )
    AND FECHA >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())

GROUP BY 

    ts.CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
    ts.FECHA

UNION ALL

SELECT 

    CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
    FECHA,
    SUM(ts.CANTIDAD) as RECEPCIONES,
    ISNULL('TRASLADOS',0) AS TRASLADOS,
    ISNULL('FACTURA',0) AS FACTURA,
    ISNULL('PRIORIDAD',0) AS PRIORIDAD


FROM 

ORACLE_INFO.dbo.tbl_TRANSACCIONES_INVENTARIO as ts

WHERE

    TRANSACTION_TYPE IN ( 'Intransit Receipt' )
    AND SUCURSAL_DESC IN ('BR_CEDIS MONTERREY')
    AND LEFT(ORIGEN, 3) = 'B10'

GROUP BY

    CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
    FECHA

UNION ALL

  -- VENTAS (FACTURAS)

SELECT 

    vta.CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
    vta.FECHA,
    MIN(vta.Factura) as FACTURA,
    ISNULL('TRASLADOS',0) AS TRASLADOS,
    ISNULL('RECEPCIONES',0) AS RECEPCIONES,
    ISNULL('PROIRIDAD',0) AS PRIORIDAD



FROM 

ORACLE_INFO.dbo.tbl_VENTA_DIARIA as vta

GROUP BY

    CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
    FECHA

UNION ALL

SELECT 

    PRODUCTO as CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
    FECHA_REPORTE AS FECHA,
    MIN(PRIORIDAD) AS PRIORIDAD,
    ISNULL('TRASLADOS',0) AS TRASLADOS,
    ISNULL('RECEPCIONES',0) AS RECEPCIONES,
    ISNULL('FACTURA',0) AS FACTURA


FROM 

ORACLE_INFO.dbo.tbl_SUG_PRODUCCION 

GROUP BY 

    FECHA_REPORTE,
    PRODUCTO


"Sé que estoy usando mal el comando ISNULL" - Entonces lee la documentación: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16. Tienes los argumentos al revés.

Creo que tienes algunas brechas de conocimiento, y considero que, además de resolver tu problema, es importante que mejore tu comprensión del funcionamiento de las consultas SQL y de sus distintos operadores. Por ello, voy a comenzar hablando de dos temas importantes de manera general (como si se tratara de un curso de SQL), para finalizar resolviendo tu consulta. Sugiero que no te saltes estas primeras secciones.
Uniones
Primero, con el funcionamiento de union all. Debes comenzar por recordar que la teoría de conjuntos es la base del modelo relacional. Si recuerdas de la matemática de primaria, las operaciones de conjuntos, hay una llamada union, representada con el operador ∪, que devuelve todos los elementos de dos conjuntos.
Digamos que tenemos estos dos conjuntos:
A = {1, 2, 3}
B = {2, 4, 6}

Entonces, operador unión nos va a devolver todos los elementos del conjunto A y todos los elementos del conjunto B, sin repetidos, por tanto, tendríamos:
A ∪ B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6}

Nota como el elemento 2, que aparecía en ambos conjuntos, aparece una sola vez en el resultado.
En SQL, el operador union hace exactamente lo mismo que el operador ∪ de conjuntos, y el operador union all devuelve todos los elementos de los dos conjuntos de datos originales, aún cuando estén repetidos.
Entonces, digamos que tenemos dos consultas q1 y q2 que devuelven, respectivamente:
q1
codigo fecha      traslados   recepciones
123    2024-06-01 100         0
123    2024-06-02 250         0
123    2024-06-03 0           0

q2
codigo fecha      traslados   recepciones
123    2024-06-01 0           148
123    2024-06-02 0           133 
123    2024-06-03 0           0

Al aplicar el operador union o union all sobre estas, vamos a obtener todos los registros ya en un solo conjunto de datos:
q1 union q2
codigo fecha      traslados   recepciones
123    2024-06-01 100         0
123    2024-06-02 250         0
123    2024-06-03 0           0
123    2024-06-01 0           148
123    2024-06-02 0           133 


q1 union all q2
codigo fecha      traslados   recepciones
123    2024-06-01 100         0
123    2024-06-02 250         0
123    2024-06-03 0           0
123    2024-06-01 0           148
123    2024-06-02 0           133 
123    2024-06-03 0           0

Debes notar la diferencia en el resultado de ambas operaciones. union all devuelve dos registros repetidos para el 3 de junio, ambos con 0 en ambas columnas, mientras que union devuelve solo uno.
Orden de las columnas
Es muy importante que sepas que, al hacer una unión de dos conjuntos de datos, los motores SQL se basan en el orden y tipo de dato de las columnas y nada más que eso. Generalmente, al conjunto de datos resultante, le ponen los nombres de las columnas del primer conjunto de datos.
Es decir, si yo tuviera los conjuntos de datos así:
q1
codigo fecha      traslados   recepciones
...

q2
codigo fecha      recepciones traslados   
...

En el resultado la tercera columna se va llamar a traslados y la cuarta recepciones, pero los datos van a estar mezclados.  Tú, como programador que escribe la consulta eres responsable de darle al motor los datos en un orden que sea coherente para las reglas del negocio en cada una de las consultas de la unión.
IsNull
La función IsNull recibe dos argumentos. Si el primero es NULL, devuelve el segundo, y si no, devuelve el primero. Usualmente se utiliza para evitar que aparezcan nulos en el resultado de una consulta y sean sustituidos por un valor por defecto. Por ejemplo:
select IsNull(Nombre, '(Sin nombre)') from Cliente

Va a devolver el nombre de todos los clientes, pero para aquellos que tengan almacenado un valor NULL en la tabla, va a devolver la cadena '(Sin nombre)', y no el valor NULL.
Como puedes ver, en tu caso, llamando a IsNull con un valor constante que no puede ser nulo en el primer argumento, siempre va a devolver ese valor, por ejemplo, ISNULL('TRASLADOS',0) nunca va a devolver 0, siempre va a devolver la cadena 'TRASLADOS'.
Resolviendo tu problema
Creo que, luego de leer estos conceptos, si lees tu consulta vas a encontrar inmediatamente varios problemas con ella.
Estoy asumiendo que lo que quieres lograr es un resumen que, por cada artículo, te diga en distintas columnas la sumatoria de valores de traslados, recepciones, etc.
La técnica que puedes utilizar para esto es la de unir los conjuntos de datos de origen, teniendo el cuidado de colocar en cada una de las distintas columnas el valor que corresponda dependiendo de la consulta y finalmente hacer el resumen, con la cláusula group by tal como la has utilizado en las consultas de ejemplo de tu pregunta.
Yo suelo hacer esto con CTE's, pues me resulta más sencillo ver cada consulta por separado e ir desarrollando el resultado paso a paso.
Así, podrías tener algo como:

Un CTE para los traslados, otro para las recepciones, facturas, etc. Teniendo el cuidado en cada uno de agregar las 3 columnas que restan con valores 0 o null, y que las columnas queden siempre en el mismo orden. Por ejemplo,

Para las recepciones:
select Codigo, Fecha, Cantidad as Recepciones, 0 as Traslados, 0 as facturas
  from TablaDeRecepciones
 where --CondicionesDeRecepcion


Para los traslados
select Codigo, Fecha, 0 as Recepciones, Cantidad as Traslados, 0 as facturas
  from TablaDeTraslados
 where --CondicionesDeTraslado


Etc.



En un nuevo CTE realizar la unión de los 4 conjuntos de datos anteriores:
  select * from CTERecepciones
  union all
  select * from CTETraslados
  union all
  ...


Finalmente, realizar el resumen por producto y fecha
  select Codigo, Fecha, sum(Recepciones) Recepciones, Sum(Traslados) Traslados, etc
    from CTEUnion
   group by Codigo, Fecha.



La estructura final, entonces, sería algo como:
;
with 
CTERecepciones as (
--La consulta de recepciones, con las columnas con los títulos, tipos de datos y en el orden definido para el resultado final
SELECT   CODIGO_PRODUCTO
       , FECHA
       , ts.CANTIDAD as RECEPCIONES
       , cast(0.0 as float) AS TRASLADOS
       , cast(null as int) AS FACTURA
       , cast(null as int) AS PRIORIDAD
  FROM ORACLE_INFO.dbo.tbl_TRANSACCIONES_INVENTARIO as ts
 WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE IN ( 'Intransit Receipt' )
   AND SUCURSAL_DESC IN ('BR_CEDIS MONTERREY')
   AND LEFT(ORIGEN, 3) = 'B10'
)
, CTETraslados as (
SELECT   CODIGO_PRODUCTO
       , FECHA
       , 0 as RECEPCIONES
       , ts.CANTIDAD as TRASLADOS
       , null AS FACTURA
       , null AS PRIORIDAD
  FROM ORACLE_INFO.dbo.tbl_TRANSACCIONES_INVENTARIO as ts
 WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE IN ( 'WIP Assy Completion' )
   AND FECHA >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
 GROUP BY ts.CODIGO_PRODUCTO, ts.FECHA
)
, CTEFacturas as (
-- la consulta de las facturas respetando el orden de las columnas
)
, CTEPrioridad as (
-- la consulta de prioridad respetando el orden de las columnas
)
, CTEUnion as (
          select * from CTERecepciones
union all select * from CTETraslados
union all select * from CTEFacturas
union all select * from CTEPrioridad
)
select   codigo_producto
       , Fecha
       , sum(Recepciones) Recepciones
       , sum(Traslados) Traslados
       , min(Factura) Factura
       , min(Prioridad) Prioridad
  from CTEUnion
 group by codigo_producto, Fecha
 order by codigo_producto, Fecha

A estas alturas, debieras ser capaz de completar la consulta real por tí mismo y eso espero que hagas.
En este último código, he dejado algunas cosas por resolver. Por ejemplo, la columna prioridad se establece como entera en el CTERecepciones, pues asumo que ese sería el tipo de dato de una columna con ese nombre, pero eres tú quien conoce el modelo y puede ajustarlo si hace falta. De manera similar, el tipo de dato de las columnas Traslados y Factura que, por ahora, se establecen a Float.
Nota como Prioridad lo voy dejando en null en las primeras consultas. Esto es porque usas la función min() al final, y si tiene valor 0, asumiendo que esa sea la prioridad más baja, el resultado podría ser incorrecto.
Si tienes alguna duda, no dudes en dejar algún comentario y con gusto vemos de qué se trata.
Como puedes ver, mi estrategia es primero unir y después agrupar, en este caso ha sido una decisión un poco arbitraria, pero también solo por el juego de darle vuelta a la idea.
Puedes lograr el mismo resultado primero agrupando, luego uniendo y finalmente agrupando otra vez. Quizás esta segunda pueda tener un mejor desempeño, pero es algo que es difícil decir de entrada y que habría que probar. Si los conjuntos de datos son pequeños o medianos, probablemente no haya una diferencia significativa. Sobre una base de datos de millones de registros, habría que tomarse el tiempo de optimizar, luego de que la consulta devuelva los valores que esperas.
Finalmente, todo esto podría escribirse son CTE's. Estos no son más que azucar sintáctica, pero, como dije al inicio, yo los uso porque, para mí, la consulta es más fácil de construir, de leer y de entender, pues cada paso queda por separado. Al final, el motor une todo y es capaz de armar un plan muy similar a si la consulta se hubiese escrito de una sola vez. Conozco programadores que prefieren eso, aunque en mi opinión, el código es más difícil de entender y, por tanto, de mantener.
Un saludo.

un saludo krnal, gracias!

Primero tienes que organizar el UNION ALL. Para eso, todas las columnas tienen que estar en el mismo orden en todas las consultas.
También tienes que tener en cuenta que no puedes hacer referencia a columnas de otra consulta. Lo que estás haciendo en el ISNULL es verificar si una cadena es nula y nunca lo será.
Para poder agrupar todo por fecha y código de producto, tienes que convertir la consulta en una tabla derivada (subconsulta) y entonces sí poder agrupar.
SELECT  CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
        FECHA,
        ISNULL( SUM( TRASLADOS), 0)   AS TRASLADOS,
        ISNULL( SUM( RECEPCIONES), 0) AS RECEPCIONES,
        ISNULL( MIN( FACTURA), 0)     AS FACTURA,
        ISNULL( MIN( PRIORIDAD), 0)   AS PRIORIDAD
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
        FECHA,
        SUM(ts.CANTIDAD) AS TRASLADOS,
        0                AS RECEPCIONES,
        NULL             AS FACTURA,
        NULL             AS PRIORIDAD
    FROM  ORACLE_INFO.dbo.tbl_TRANSACCIONES_INVENTARIO as ts
    WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE IN ( 'WIP Assy Completion' )
    AND   FECHA >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY 
        ts.CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
        ts.FECHA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
        FECHA,
        0                AS TRASLADOS,
        SUM(ts.CANTIDAD) AS RECEPCIONES,
        NULL             AS FACTURA,
        NULL             AS PRIORIDAD
    FROM ORACLE_INFO.dbo.tbl_TRANSACCIONES_INVENTARIO as ts
    WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE IN ( 'Intransit Receipt' )
    AND   SUCURSAL_DESC IN ('BR_CEDIS MONTERREY')
    AND   LEFT(ORIGEN, 3) = 'B10'
    GROUP BY
        CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
        FECHA
    UNION ALL
    -- VENTAS (FACTURAS)
    SELECT 
        vta.CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
        vta.FECHA,
        0                AS TRASLADOS,
        0                AS RECEPCIONES,
        MIN(vta.Factura) AS FACTURA,
        NULL             AS PRIORIDAD
    FROM ORACLE_INFO.dbo.tbl_VENTA_DIARIA as vta
    GROUP BY 
        CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
        FECHA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        PRODUCTO         AS CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
        FECHA_REPORTE    AS FECHA,
        0                AS TRASLADOS,
        0                AS RECEPCIONES,
        NULL             AS FACTURA,
        MIN(PRIORIDAD)   AS PRIORIDAD
    FROM ORACLE_INFO.dbo.tbl_SUG_PRODUCCION 
    GROUP BY FECHA_REPORTE,
        PRODUCTO
    )T
GROUP BY CODIGO_PRODUCTO,
        FECHA;


Muchas gracias por la ayuda, respecto al query que hiciste, tengo una duda con la tabla de resultados. Los valores no tienen coincidencia entre sí (ya me habia pasado antes), sabes a que se debe?... Por ejemplo, la columna de TRASLADOS me arroja puros valores en 0, hasta cierto numero me empieza a dar valores de los TRASLADOS pero no son coincidentes con las otras columnas
